# Declare a resource-ref in EJB

Tags: ejb, jndi, websphere-6.1, ejb-jar.xml

This is how they declare a resource-ref in ejb-jar.xml :

```
<enterprise-beans>
<session>
<ejb-name>ResourceBean</ejb-name>
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/employee</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
</session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

at this link: http://javahowto.blogspot.ca/2006/06/5-ways-to-get-resources-in-ejb-3.html
Now if I have another session bean that needs to use the same resource-ref, do I have to declare it again inside the second EJB? Or is there  a workaround?

Comment: Note that the XML syntax you shown is more used these days to override an injection annotation instead of being the primary source to declare injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to EE 6 (available in WebSphere Application Server 8.0), there is no way to share `resource-ref` across EJBs.  You must redeclare the `resource-ref` in each EJB.

In EE 6, you can declare the resource-ref with a name such as `java:module/env/jdbc/employee`, and it will be visible to all EJBs in the module (and `java:app` is visible to all modules, and `java:global` is visible to all apps).

Comment: You said to **declare the resource-ref with a name such as `java:module/env/jdbc/employee`**. I am assuming you are talking about declaring it in `ejb-jar.xml`. Correct? If yes then which version of xsd to use? If not then which file to declare this? Thanks

Comment: @ChumboChappati Yes, in ejb-jar.xml or an annotation; for java:app or java:global, you could also use application.xml.  If ejb-jar.xml, then it doesn't matter which version of the XSD you use because it's just a string name.  For application.xml, you would need the applicaition_6.xsd.